# How do I extract text from images in terminal?

Tags: command-line, pdf, preview, graphics, text

I know how to extract text from images using preview.app, however I would like to use this feature from terminal to extract all the text from a bunch of images.
I tried this using [this method](https://www.idownloadblog.com/2013/10/19/how-to-resize-multiple-images-mac/) to apply same operation to multiple images but it doesn't work (it select text from only one image at time).

I also tried converting the images into one pdf, but the text selection doesn't work anymore.

I found no macOS apps or utilities I could use for extract the text from my image(s) from terminal.

Right now I used the proprietary Apple's text recognition machine learning new capabilities (on [macOS](https://support.apple.com/en-gb/guide/preview/prvw625a5b2c/11.0/mac/12.0) and [iOS](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT212630), [here](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/vision/recognizing_text_in_images) it's explained how to use their Vision framework).

Any idea?

Comment: How exactly did you apply the linked method to extract text? Can you loop over all the images, collecting the extracted text in a text file?

Comment: Of course I could loop over the images, but I found no macos apps or utilities I could use for this from terminal (I edited my question to explain what I tried).

Comment: I was referring to "I tried this using this method to apply same operation to multiple images but it doesn't work (it select text from only one image at time)". How exactly did you extract the text of one image?

Comment: I added an explanation. Right now I used the proprietary Apple's text recognition machine learning new capabilities

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In terminal:

`brew install tesseract` <- this installs the program you need (I assume that you have brew installed, if not, go to this website: https://brew.sh/).

For one image you do this: `tesseract my.png textfile`

And you get a `textfile.txt` from that image. It should work with other image formats as well.

In order to loop over all images in some directory, you can do this:

```
for x in ~/Desktop/*.png; do
    tesseract ${x} ${x} 
done
```

In this case I am looping over all the png images on my Desktop and creating a `.txt` file for each one of them.

If you want more formats you can specify them like so:

`~Desktop/(*.png|*.jpeg|*.jpg|*.bmp)`

Comment: Thanks, I will try this. Howerver I would like to understand if there is any way to use the Apple ML api with some standalone terminal utilities.

Comment: How do you expect to use an ML API from the command line? It sounds strange. I think you have to write a Swift application in Xcode with apple's vision framework, or something. Why do you need to use an apple api specifically, if tesseract gets the job done? Tesseract seems to be the most popular OCR tool, even iOS developers use it in their apps. It is also developed by google, so I think its quality should be good.

Comment: @ArtemBernatskyi it works well with text. Why don't you recommend another library then, with proof that it is better?

Comment: sure, I could be biased but after 2 days I found out that this somewhat works https://github.com/open-mmlab/mmocr and this https://github.com/JaidedAI/EasyOCR , but (lol), what I actually ended using is build-in OCR in MacOS (VNRecognizeTextRequest API) via some noname script from github . I was using this (https://github.com/xulihang/macOCR) but there are tons of others (or you can even write yourself), they basically are wrappers around Apple's VNRecognizeTextRequest API.

Comment: and tessaract it total garbage compared to all of them lol, I thought that after 8 years of development (I haven't touched tessaract in 8 years) they will come up with new and better tessaract versions but ... no. OK, no problem, will switch to another solution:)

Comment: talk is cheap, so here is an example of https://github.com/xulihang/macOCR , here I took image and detected text in it and then overlayed that text on to the same image and filtered where model is at least 50% confident , if you can detect text with the same quality using tessaract -props to you then, but I doubt  https://bernatskyys.s3.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/20a99003-6ab7-4538-89b4-454695f2772a.png

Comment: @ArtemBernatskyi cool, maybe your should post another answer on here.

Comment: Tesseract was the best option so far. It did a much better job than Preview!

Answer (score 10):

I did this using Shortcuts on Mac OS, creating the [following shortcut](https://www.icloud.com/shortcuts/ddd02d1582d849ff8e9f9ed938e66453):

[image: A screenshot of the shortcut recipe]

Then executing the shortcut from the command line or a script:

```
shortcuts run "extract_text_from_image" -i input.png -o output.txt
```

I played with Tesseract too, but it seems more focused on the traditional OCR case (extract text from a scanned document or book), this method seems to do way better extracting random text from images.

Comment: I use the same trick to automatically sort incoming invoices to relevant files.

Comment: I will try this also, thank you